# Ajax function , or ) expected

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, django

So I'm following a tutorial trying to implement an Ajax search form on my site, my Ajax.js looks as follows:

```
$(funcrion () {
$('#search').keyup(function () {
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "/cooks/search/",
        data: {
            'search_text': $('#search').val(),
            'csrfmiddlewaretoken': $("input[name=csrfmiddlewaretoken]").val()
        },
        success: searchSuccess,
        dataType: 'html'
    });
});
});
```

From what I understood the first bit is to make sure the search function doesn't run before the page loads.
I'm getting a ", or ) expected " error although the syntax seems to match the tutorials.

mind that I have an on load function on my base.html (don't know if that's related)

```
 $( window ).on( "load", function() {
            console.log( "window loaded" );
        });
```

What am I missing here?

ps.
I don't want massive lines of code on my HTML for the ajax so I rather have a separate js file for that

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have a typo in the very first word :) I'm guessing that's why you're getting an error.

You have
"$(funcrion () {"

And it should be
"$(function () {"

Comment: Jeez, that hurt, thanks.

Comment: No problem, if it solved your issue, please mark the answer as such.

Comment: Typo-questions should be deleted, not answered with accepted answers.